# Need to understand why this isn't working | Accepting SerialPort data in QT Widget Application

Tags: c++, qt, widget, serial-port

I'm always desperate when going to Stackoverflow for help, but my deadline is near and it's too late to change project.

I've a IR Remote that sends commands/text from Cube IDE to the serial port that I want my QT Widget application to pick up and control the snake in my game. I've come so far as QT picks upp the sent data and displays the text in the QT cmd.
I've after trying different methods stayed at the method that if for example I receive an "Up" a QKeyEvent is called with the key `Qt::Key_Down` to the `keyPressEvent` function.
I was first confused on why the worm never moved so I put a `qDebug() << "Went inside if statement keyPressEvent";` inside the function that makes the worm move and it does enter the function but the `m_rkDirection = RK(1,0);` that changes the direction of the worm doesn't seem to be excecuted.
I'm suspecting that this has something to do with threads, that maybe the SerialReader() function is on a different thread and thus can't change the direction of the worm maybe? I've not yet studied threads so I don't know much of how they work. Didn't think I needed them when I started this project (and maybe I dont).

It's lots of code and it's probably hard to help me but I thought it was worth a shot to ask.

After receiving data in the serialport function it calls the RemotePressEvent function who send a QKeyEvent to the keyPressEvent function (and i know about the potential memory leak). When I press the physical key on my keyboard it moves, but when calling the same function when pressing on my remote it doesn't.

Not all files but the most important ones I guess:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "playground.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    // Start serial reading in a separate thread
    QThread serialThread;
    Playground playground;

    SerialReader reader(&playground);
    reader.moveToThread(&serialThread);

    QObject::connect(&serialThread, &QThread::started, &reader, &SerialReader::readSerial);

    serialThread.start();

    int result = a.exec();

    // Cleanup and exit
    serialThread.quit();
    serialThread.wait();

    return result;
}
```

serialport.cpp

```
#include "serialport.h"
#include "playground.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QThread>
#include <QKeyEvent>


//SerialReader::SerialReader(Playground* playground, QObject* parent) : QObject(parent), m_playground(playground)
SerialReader::SerialReader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void SerialReader::readSerial()
{
    QSerialPort serialPort("COM9");

    if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qWarning() << "Failed to open serial port:" << serialPort.errorString();
        return;
    }

    // Configure the serial port settings
    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    qDebug() << "Listening for data ..." << serialPort.portName() << "...";

    // Connect a signal to handle the incoming data
    QObject::connect(&serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, [&serialPort]() {
        QByteArray data = serialPort.readAll();

        qDebug() << "Received data:" << data;

        Playground playground;

        playground.RemotePressEvent(data);

    });

    while (true) {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        QThread::msleep(50); // Add a delay of x milliseconds between iterations
    }
}
```

playground.cpp

```
#include "playground.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <QColor>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
```

/ Other methods /

```
void Playground::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    int k = event->key();
    //qDebug() << "Keypress" << k;

    if(!gameIsOver){
        if (k == Qt::Key_Down && m_rkDirection.m_r != -1){
            qDebug() << "Went inside if statement keyPressEvent";
            m_rkDirection = RK(1,0);
        }
        if (k == Qt::Key_Up && m_rkDirection.m_r != 1) m_rkDirection = RK(-1,0);
        if (k == Qt::Key_Left && m_rkDirection.m_k != 1) m_rkDirection = RK(0,-1);
        if (k == Qt::Key_Right && m_rkDirection.m_k != -1) m_rkDirection = RK(0,1);
    }
    / Other methods /
}

void Playground::RemotePressEvent(QByteArray data){
    qDebug() << "Sent: " << data;
    if (data == "Down" && m_rkDirection.m_r != -1){
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Down, Qt::NoModifier);
        keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
    }
    if (data == "Up"){
        m_rkDirection = RK(-1,0);
        qDebug() << "Up";
    }
    if (data == "<" && m_rkDirection.m_k != 1){
        m_rkDirection = RK(0,-1);
        qDebug() << "Left";
    }
    if (data == ">" && m_rkDirection.m_k != -1){
        m_rkDirection = RK(0,1);
        qDebug() << "Right";
    }
}

/ Other methods /
```

Thanks!

Comment: no matter how close the deadline, when you find it hard to debug because its too much code you should create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes I understand. I'll edit the post and remove the unessecary parts.

Comment: removing the includes made your code less of a [mcve] not more of it. A [mre] is a complete example that has only what is necessary to reproduce the issue. For some reason it is believed that removing includes from code makes it easier to read, the opposite is true

Comment: Damn it. I've removed uneccesary functions atleast. I'll add back the libraries.

Comment: frankly, you misunderstood because you didnt read the link. Its described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Especially: "Complete: Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself" and "Reproducible: Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem". Its not your whole project, and often its also not your whole project with some parts removed, but requires you to create a new fresh project with only the code necessary to reproduce the issue

Comment: `Playground playground;` in `SerialReader::readSerial()` is a object local to the lambda. It has no relation to any other `Playground` elsewhere in the code. It is not the `Playground playground` in `main`

Comment: I'll try to make a more minimal reproducible example.

I was suspecting something like that. Stuff like that always confuses me, I'll have to learn more about different instances. How can I access the playground instance inside `playground.cpp` to be able to read and change the variables from `SerialReader::readSerial()`? 

I tried making the SerialReader class a friend of the playground class, is that the right approach?

Comment: I dont know how to access it, because the relevant details are missing or I didnt find them. In `main` you pass a pointer to the playground here `SerialReader reader(&playground);` perhaps you just have to use it

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I managed to fix it by using threads after looking into it more. I created a new thread class inside the Playground h file and connected dataReceived and handleReceivedData in the Playground constructor and it works perfectly now.